# Botão de ctrl + c no typescript, Ionic

Tags: ionic, typescript

Boa tarde, estou tentando criar um botão para copiar o texto de um input, porém sem sucesso, estou tentando com clipboard e não funciona, dá um erro dizendo que 'copy()' não é uma função. segue o código:

Typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, AbstractControl, FormControl} from '@angular/forms'
import { Clipboard } from '@ionic-native/clipboard/ngx';


/**
 * Generated class for the TestePage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-teste',
  templateUrl: 'teste.html',
})
export class TestePage {
private orderForm: FormGroup
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
     public navParams: NavParams, 
     public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
     private clipboard: Clipboard

  ) { let texto = navParams.get('texto');

  this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    resultado: texto
  })
  }



  copy(){
    // copy function
    this.clipboard.copy('Hello world').then(rs => {
     alert(rs);
   }).catch(error => {
     alert(error);
   })
  }



  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestePage');
  }

}
```

html:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>

    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>
    <form [formGroup]="orderForm" novalidate>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label></ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="resultado" readonly></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <button ion-button (click)="copy()" >  <ion-icon ios="ios-copy" md="md-copy"></ion-icon>
      </button>





</form> 

</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Você está testando em um emulador ou direto no navegador ? Porque esse plugin, pelo que eu pesquisei, não possui implementação no Browser, logo, chamar qualquer função dele daria erro.

Comment: Realmente, pelo que eu pesquisei seria isso mesmo, sabe alguma outra solução para desktop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução para o desktop seria assim:

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({ selector: '[copy-clipboard]' })
export class CopyClipboardDirective {

  @Input("copy-clipboard")
  public payload: string;

  @Output("copied")
  public copied: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  public onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {

    event.preventDefault();
    if (!this.payload)
      return;

    let listener = (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
      let clipboard = e.clipboardData || window["clipboardData"];
      clipboard.setData("text", this.payload.toString());
      e.preventDefault();

      this.copied.emit(this.payload);
    };

    document.addEventListener("copy", listener, false)
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.removeEventListener("copy", listener, false);
  }
}
```

E adicione no seu `app.module.ts` a diretiva, assim:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    CopyClipboardDirective //added here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> O link da resposta original você pode encontrar [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52949299/8741188).

Essa é uma diretiva que você pode colocar diretamente no botão em que você quer que seja clicado para ativar a cópia. Para o seu caso, a implementação ficaria assim:

No arquivo HTML.

```
<button ion-button [copy-clipboard]="dataParaACopia">  
    <ion-icon ios="ios-copy" md="md-copy"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

No arquivo ts:

```
public dataParaACopia: string = "O texto que será copiado para o seu clipboard";
```

---

Uma solução sem diretiva, seria assim:

No `.html`:

```
<button ion-button (click)="copyForClipboard($event)">  
    <ion-icon ios="ios-copy" md="md-copy"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

No arquivo `.ts`:

```
public copyForClipboard(event: MouseEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    const payload: string = "A informação que será copiada.";

    let listener = (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
      let clipboard = e.clipboardData || window["clipboardData"];
      clipboard.setData("text", payload.toString());
      e.preventDefault();
    };

    document.addEventListener("copy", listener, false)
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.removeEventListener("copy", listener, false);
}
```

---

Em paralelo, você pode utilizar ambas as soluções para o que você quer fazer, utilize a classe `Platform` e seu método chamado `is` para identificar em qual plataforma o usuário está, e assim, utilizar a solução adequada para cada plataforma ( a diretiva no browser e o plugin no dispositivo ).

Comment: Essa primeira parte, eu crio um arquivo ts novo e coloco isso? ou dentro do próprio arquivo ts da page ?

Comment: @Israel você cria um novo arquivo, eu recomendo criar uma pasta chamada `directives` e adicionar lá o `copy-clipboard.directive.ts` e colocar esse código lá.

Comment: Desculpa a demora do feedback, acabei tento um outro projeto na frente. Fiz o que você passou, mas está dando o seguinte erro: Can't bind to 'copy-clipboard' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Comment: Isso é um problema para quando ele não encontra a diretiva. Você adicionou a classe da diretiva no `app.module.ts` ? Se sim, experimente reiniciar o `ionic serve` após fazer isso.

Comment: Sim, adicionei  na parte de declarations, criei uma pasta directive e criei o arquivo ts e coloquei o que mandou, já reiniciei o ionic serve tb, mas o erro continua, só reforçando que estou usando o ionic 3.9.2

Comment: Eu atualizei a resposta para uma forma sem a diretiva, mas poste aqui o erro completo que está ocorrendo para que a gente possa tentar resolver também.

Comment: Obrigado lourenço, agora foi!. Fica difícil postar o erro pois ele acontece no trabalho e só consigo acessar o stack em casa, Mas valeu mesmo cara! Abraço.